# Do I need to register app.com and api.app.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, subdomain

I am developing a rails api to work with angularjs FE app and with several other mobile application. Since I have developed separately, do I need to host separately ? If so then how to manage domains?

Answer (score 0):

`api.domain.com` is a sub-domain. You need to add an A-Record of this in your domain and point it where ever you want to.

Comment: So if I host the apps in two different places, still I can buy one domain and access both right?

Comment: So if I host the apps in two different places, still I can buy one domain and access both right?

Comment: Yes, you can buy one domain and have multiple sub-domains and each one of it can point to different app.

Answer (score 0):

You can host in sites like heroku.com as they do provide free tier for basic usages. They also do provide free domain for your rails app.

Comment: I am in fact using heroku to host my rails app currently. The problem is I want to separate FE files as a html5 app and communicate to rails app via json api. This is where I am confused, on how to execute that project. So am just developing an AngularJS app and Rails API. So the question of hosting popped up.